# segmentation fault (core dumped) in Ubuntu/Debian

Tags: segmentation-fault, debian, ubuntu-16.04

I have a program which loads a tree structure with data from a .txt file.
I have different .txt files with smaller and bigger trees.
When I run the program on my Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop computer everything works fine.
When I run the program on my Ubuntu 16.04 or Debian server I get an error with the big trees. "segmentation fault (core dumped)"
The small trees work fine.

I already increased the RAM of my server and reuploaded the files.

Do you have an idea how to solve the problem? I am lost.

Comment: Impossible to solve without seeing your code

Comment: I do not have the source code. I bought the software. I think it is a Ubuntu problem because on my Desktop everything works fine.